# A quick puzzle (Day 1)- What am I?

Tags: riddle

You can give me anything, I will shrink it and hand it back.

Give it to me again, and I will return it to full size

What am I?

Comment: ANSWER ACCEPTED, though if you have **other** ideas as an answer, go ahead!

Comment: Riddles should have *one* answer. If they have more than one equally valid answer, they are too broad and should be closed.

Comment: Also, please check tag wikis before using them - this is *not* a [logical-deduction] puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi I'll check now. Also, they are not equally valid, just alternatives no-one thinks of.

Comment: The validity of an answer does not depend on how many people think of that answer. The usual "just because you didn't think of it doesn't mean no one will" word of advice also applies here. A "less valid" answer to a riddle would be something like an answer that requires a leap in logic or an answer that doesn't doesn't fully fit the clues.

Comment: @DennisMeng Well that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be

> A zipping program (winzip, winrar, etc)

Reason is pretty self explanatory.

> Zipping files reduces size, the program will also unzip which brings it back to its original size.

Comment: I was going for compression, but meh, close enough. The quick puzzles are better, I think; they allow even the nubs to have a good go. I'll mark it ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer

> Shrinking and Growing Head Illusion

The reason:

> The illusion is supposed to make the mind think an object is either growing or shrinking based off of a spiraling circle.

Comment: Inventive, I will give you that. Not what I was looking for, but meh, illusions.

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> the inverse operation, $\large1/\underline~$; 
> i.e., the function $f(x)=\large\frac1x$.

> $\color{black}{\text{If you give it }}\text{a number > 1, }$
> $\color{black}{\text{it will “hand” you }}$
> $\text{the inverse of that number, }$
> $\text{which}$ $\text{will}$ $\text{be < 1 (and > 0).}$  
> $\color{black}{\text{Submit that }}\text{value to the function}$
> $\color{black}{\text{again, }}$
> $\color{black}{\text{and}}$ $\color{black}{\text{it}}$
> $\color{black}{\text{will}}$ $\color{black}{\text{return}}$
> $\color{black}{\text{the}}$ $\color{black}{\text{original}}$ $\text{number.}$

The argument can be made
that this technically doesn't satisfy the terms of the question,
because you (obviously) can't give it ***just anything***. 
There are some things that you can give it
that will cause it to give you a larger thing. 
But that's true for the accepted answer, too,
and I'd be interested in seeing an answer that *does*
literally answer the question.

Comment: Hmmm. I see where you are coming from. Well, If we see something like that, you can say 'I told you so" :)